# MySQL help about CASE WHEN query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am not sure what is mistake, i want to use `CASE WHEN` in SQL query, and where is `499` to say `Country`, for all else to put `Test`, but it gives on all result word `Test`, i don't get it why, when in result i see `499`? Can someone help me?

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, drzavljanstvo, 
        ( CASE WHEN  drzavljanstvo=(
            SELECT id_drzavljanstvo from drzavljanstvo WHERE id_drzavljanstvo=499) 
            THEN 'Country' ELSE 'Test' END) location 
FROM bol_rac;
```

Result looks like this

[image]

Comment: what is the error message you are getting ?

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan i don't get error message it give back result, but on value where is 499 it don't put country it put everywhere 'Test'

Comment: probably your query doesn't take things from then but takes from else.Is it not possible to give it in where instead of then

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan if i understand you good, you think that i should put "Contry" under Else, but when i do that, again, everyone become Country and there is no 'Test'

Comment: No search for an alternative instead of using THEN

Comment: Are you sure the table `drzavljanstvo` does contain a row with `id=499`? Also, you may want to have a look into `left join`.

Comment: @Solarflare yes, it contains, i don't get it why it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you need the subquery? Just use `CASE WHEN drzavljanstvo = 499`

Comment: Your code works here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce334/1

Comment: As Barmer kindly showed in the fiddle, the query is fine (apart from being to complicated, but that is a different topic) and the problem is probably your data. If you have verified that a row with id = 499 exist, check that your (varchar?)-column `drzavljanstvo` actually contains `499`, and not e.g. an additional space (although it should autocast as an int, but might be a good point to start your investigation).

Comment: Thank all on helps, i also think i must to check types of data, that is possible making problem, because i also see query is definetly working as Barmar show, for first comment @Barnar that work, first i done like this, but i wanted to create subquery. Thanks